# Menu button positioning

Tags: html, css, sass, css-position

I am currently following along this HTML/SCSS/JavaScript tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WaohfclZRs&list=PLillGF-RfqbYoGoCjKoMOkVznV6aSXKzU&index=3.

I believe I did everything like in the video but my menu-button isn't positioned in the right way.

[The menu btn is always positioned relative to the header element, even though I added a absolute position element to my menu btn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEdsw.png)

```css
.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 35px;
  top: 35px;
  @include ease-out;}

header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2; }
```

```html
<body id="bg-img">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <header>
      <div class="menu-btn">
        <div class="btn-line"></div>
        <div class="btn-line"></div>
        <div class="btn-line"></div>
      </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

The first two snippets are from my _menu.scss and main.scss files, the last one from my index.html file.

[Here's how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzjef.png)

[And here's how it is looking like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwR7b.png)

Thanks for every help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see. Your header is kinda short... so try adding width: 100%; - that should make that menu fullwidth.

```
header{
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But why isn't it working without? I thought the position: absolute element makes the menu btn independent from the header element.

Comment: @DerOeko it depends.... I dont know what other CSS or frameworks you have included.... Absolute element is dependend on first position:relative parent... so that basicly means your header is somewhere set to position:relative.... if you want it to be independend you need to set your header on position:static; or put your button outside of header element.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't watch the video, but I've taken the liberty to refactor your code slightly. Your next step would probably be to make this menu fully responsive with media queries ;-)

```css
.menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 35px;
    top: 35px;
    @include ease-out;
}

.header {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="btn-line">Home</div>
    <div class="btn-line">About me</div>
    <div class="btn-line">My work</div>
    <div class="menu-btn">Place your icon here</div>
</div class="header">
```